# How to migrate the SQL Server instance and system databases to a different drive (mapped to a different letter) on the same server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, instance, system-databases

I'm tasked with moving our SQL Server instance and system databases from the existing drive it's on to a new drive on the same server. I know I can stop the SQL Server service, literally move the instance and database files to the new drive and start the service again, but the drive is going to be mapped to a different letter.

I'm guessing I'll need to update the database file paths for the system databases to point to the new drive letter.

What else do I need to do to reconfigure the instance so that's pointing to the correct drive, to ensure it works properly when I start the service again?

Edit: It sounds like this Microsoft doc is pretty encompassing of what to do, especially from the system database perspective, but are there any other steps or gotchas I should be aware of from the instance perspective: [Move System Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15)

Note: I am unable to re-use the same drive letter for business reasons.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this.  Change the drive letter on the new drive once you've moved everything.  If you can't do that, uninstall SQL Server, reinstall it on the new drive, restore the last backup of you master and msdb databases, and mount your user databases.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Sorry I added to the body now, I meant to mention I'm unable to re-use the drive letter for business reasons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917495/move-sql-sever-installation-to-another-drive if you really want to do it.  The thing to think about--if something goes wrong two months after you do this, you'll be wondering about the impact of doing this.

Comment: It doesn't take that long to uninstall and reinstall.  You'll sleep better if you do that.  The only halfway difficult thing is restoring master, but you can practice that on a test server.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Thanks, I'm reading into the resources you replied with now. I hate to see David Brown comment against doing this too so it sounds pretty risky. I'm looking closer into my requirements and I might've been mistaken as well. The folder that needs to be moved is called MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER and below it is the folder MSSQL which inside of that has the DATA folder for the system databases, and empty JOBS folder, and the Log folder (which I guess has the server logs?). Is this folder "MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER" the SQL Server instance itself or is it safe to move this?

Comment: Yes, that is where the files for the instance are stored.

Comment: This is one reason you should always install the SQL Server binaries on the OS disk.  Databases can be moved, but moving the SQL Server binaries requires uninstall/reinstall.  And you never want to run uninstall/reinstall on a production server.  Although it _should_ work there's a lot that can go wrong, or be missed in the move.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Gotcha, unfortunately this is something I've inherited. We're going to hold off on moving the SQL instance for now and only move the user DBs instead. But we'll inevitably need to move the SQL instance in the near future and I will look into going the uninstall / reinstall route. Unfortunately this is a production server which can't sustain much downtime, and I don't know how the original installation was configured, so I have a feeling I'll have a lot of work ahead of me ensuring I replicate the same settings and configurations, including some AGs, Linked Servers, etc.

Comment: Ended up making a compromise. We did physically move the instance and system database files to a different drive but re-mapped the drive letters themselves so that it was still referable as the original drive. Fingers crossed nothing bites us in the butt later down the line.